# Regex working in with <input pattern="x"> but not with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried this regular expression:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d
```

in an input of type text, where it worked as it should:

```
<input type="Text" pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d"  title="Must be DD.MM.YYYY (ex: 29.11.2012)" class="std_input_long" id="toDate">
```

However when I try to do it in JavaScript using a regular expression object it just doesn't work, anyone that can figure this out.

JavaScript:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d');
var startDate = "23.11.2012";
var endDate = "11.12.2012";
var bStartDate = regex.test(startDate);
alert(bStartDate);
if (bStartDate) {
    var bendDate = regex.test(endDate);
    alert(bendDate);
    if (bendDate) {
        alert('both correct')
    } else {
        alert('End date incorrect must be DD.MM.YYYY \n\n\
               Example: 29.11.2012');
    }
} else {
    alert('Start date incorrect must be DD.MM.YYYY \n\n\
               Example: 29.11.2012');
}​
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXPBX/) to experiment with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
var regex = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d/;
```

String literals go through interpretation before being passed to the regex engine, for instance `'\.'` would be same as `/./` and `'\d'` the same as `/d/`

Comment: However, that should still make the date valid (because `.` is more general than `\.`). And I am not questioning that your answer solves the problem (I tried the same), but I still wonder why using the RegExp constructor doesn't work.

Comment: @m.buettner that was just an example, anything in the regex with \ will be screwed (Unless accounted for with double escaping), such as `'\d'`

Comment: Right, I overlooked the `\d` at the end.

Comment: never use new regex if your regex is a constant, with regex literal, you don't have to double escape and what you see is what the regex engine sees (WYSIWTRES)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in the regular expression string:

```
"(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\\.(19|20)\\d\\d"
```

It is easier, though, to use regular expression literals, for instance:

```
/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d/.test("23.11.2012")
```

or with a string method:

```
"23.11.2012".match(/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d/)
```